# Truncating a version number C#

Tags: c#, .net, version

If I have a version number that has 5 digits such as "1.0.420.50.0", how could I truncate this number (and other version numbers like "1.0.512.500.0") to only 4 digits? "1.0.420.50.0" --> "1.0.420.50"

I would prefer to use an array but any other methods work too!
Thanks for any advice in advance!

Comment: var newString = String.Join(".", oldString.Split('.').Take(4));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't programmed in c# in a while so the syntax may be off. If the versioning can be more than six digits, you won't want a method that relies on removing the last digit. Instead just take the first four version numbers.

```
String version = "1.0.420.50.0";
String [] versionArray = version.Split(".");
var newVersion = string.Join(".", versionArray.Take(4));
```

Comment: You could do `var newVersion = string.Join(".", versionArray.Take(4));` instead.  That would work even if the original has less than 4.

Comment: You don't need that last line now as `string.Join` doesn't add a trailing delimiter.

Comment: @juharr Thanks! I wasn't aware of string.Join.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a string, you could do something like

```
ver = "1.2.3.4.5";
ver = ver.substring(0, ver.lastindexof(".");
```

this should give you all the way up to the last ".". This is not very robust if your version numbers get longer or shorter, but it would work for a 5 digit version number. This is also the basic idea you want if you have a string.

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of the last period and then get the substring from index 0 to the index of the last period. EX:

```
string version = "1.0.420.50.0";
int lastPeriodIndex = version.LastIndexOf('.');
string reformattedVersion = version.Substring(0, lastPeriodIndex);
```

through using an array, if that's what you really want:

```
string version = "1.0.420.50";
var numbers = version.Split(new char[]{'.'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string reformattedVersion = numbers[0] + '.' + numbers[1] + '.' + numbers[2] + '.' + numbers[3];
```

but that's a much less elegant/quick solution.